# Facebook Like with "total likes"-callback?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I would like to build a Facebook Like-functionality for a video competition (currently not connected with Facebook in any way) where the like button gets the total amount of likes as a callback when clicked so that I can save it in my database and use as the primary voting system.

Is it possible to build this solution, preferably in Javascript?

**EDIT:**

What I want to do is

- Implement a "Like"-button
- When clicked, like request is sent to Facebook
- When the request is processed, a callback function is activated.
- The callback function gets the total amount of likes as a parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along those lines:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // user clicked like
  var query = FB.Data.query('SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://example.com/current_url"');
  query.wait(function(rows) {
    alert('number of likes ' + rows[0].like_count;
  });
});
```

`edge.create` is an event that should be fired when a user likes a page ([see here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe)). For some reason I couldn't make it work a few months ago though.

Comment: Serg's code snippet above totally works. (Thanks!) You can see a list of all the stuff that you have accesss to from Facebook here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ ...I have a related question (I want to find out if the current user has "like"d the page or not, on pageload) which I'll ask elsewhere and point to this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understood question. But what the problem?

Click handler send ajax request -> server side code return total amount
-> ajax request callback drow it.

Comment: it is Facebook or your platform?

Comment: My platform, I have an application id to use with the Javascript SDK but my platform is in no other way connected with Facebook. I just want to use "Like" as a voting system and I need to save the total amount of likes in my database in order to perform sorting on votes.